# Is there an ASP.NET pagination control (Not MVC)?

Tags: asp.net, pagination

I've got a search results page that basically consists of a repeater with content in it.  What I need is a way to paginate the results.  Getting paginated results isn't the problem, what I'm after is a web control that will display a list of the available paged data, preferably by providing the number of results and a page size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Repeaters don't do this by default.

However, GridViews do.

Personally, I hate GridViews, so I wrote a Paging/Sorting Repeater control.

Basic Steps:

- Subclass the Repeater Control
- Add a private PagedDataSource to it
- Add a public PageSize property
- Override Control.DataBind

  - Store the Control.DataSource in the PagedDataSource.
  - Bind the Control.DataSource to PagedDataSource
- Override Control.Render

  - Call Base.Render()
  - Render your paging links.

For a walkthrough, you could try this link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210925054103/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx

Comment: is rolling your own paginated repeater worth not using a gridview?